# MVC Controller, Action Filters not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I want to add Bearer Authentication for the Controllers but it is not running the code from  the Action Filter.
I tried to add `Debug.WriteLine(...);` but it dont show anything in the output.

fetch:

```
fetch('api/Test/Select', {
   headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem("token")}`,
   },
   method: 'GET',
})
```

and the MVC Controller:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace API
{
    [BearerAuthentication] //<-- Action Filter
    [Route("api/Test")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        //...

       [HttpGet("Select")]
       public IActionResult Select()
       {
           try
           {
              return Ok(FirstService.Select());
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
              return Conflict(ex);
           }
       }
//...
```

Action Filter:

```
    public class BearerAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext context)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Why are u not working?"); //<-- Debug Console shows nothing

            HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;
            AuthenticationHeaderValue authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;

            //...
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd extend the built in authentication mechanisms instead of trying to roll your ow

Comment: I agree with @DanielA.White, use the Authorization filter for authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that your `BearerAuthenticationAttribute` class extends the `ActionFilterAttribute` class but does not implement the `IActionFilter` interface.  Your class must explicitly implement the `IActionFilter` interface for the `OnActionExecuting` method to fire.

Here is an example of the implementation from [a Microsoft Hands On Lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters):

```
public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // TODO: Add your action filter's tasks here

        // Log Action Filter call
        using (MusicStoreEntities storeDb = new MusicStoreEntities())
        {
            ActionLog log = new ActionLog()
            {
                Controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
                Action = string.Concat(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName, " (Logged By: Custom Action Filter)"),
                IP = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress,
                DateTime = filterContext.HttpContext.Timestamp
            };
            storeDb.ActionLogs.Add(log);
            storeDb.SaveChanges();
            OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your authentication method is bearer, then you can just do `[Authorize]` and don't forget to use `[ApiController]` so .net knows it needs to verify each endpoint setup:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace API
{
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/Test")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        //...

       [HttpGet("Select")]
       public IActionResult Select()
       {
           try
           {
              return Ok(FirstService.Select());
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
              return Conflict(ex);
           }
       }
//...
```